# ¿Como protejo rutas y funciones de un controlador con middleware personalizados en laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo `middleware` personalizados para las rutas y para las funciones del `CRUD`.

El de las rutas me funciona perfecto, pero el de las funciones no.

Constructor de cada controlador, este ej es el de Usuarios:

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth){
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('ruta:Usuarios');
        $this->middleware('funciones:Usuarios,crear',['only'=>['crear']]);
        $this->middleware('funciones:Usuarios,editar',['only'=>['editar']]);
        $this->middleware('funciones:Usuarios,eliminar',['only'=>['eliminar']]);
        $this->middleware('funciones:Usuarios,estado',['only'=>['estado']]);
}
```

Paso como parámetro el controlador en el que esta, en este caso es el de Usuarios.

El middleware de las rutas:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use Debugbar;

class Ruta{

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth){
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ruta){
        $results = DB::select('select exists(select * FROM perfiles_funciones AS pf INNER JOIN funciones AS f ON f.id = pf.id_funciones INNER JOIN perfiles AS p ON p.id = pf.id_perfiles WHERE pf.id_perfiles = :id AND f.titulo = :ruta) as "exists"', 
            [
            'id' => ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles),
            'ruta'=>($ruta)
            ]);
        if(!$results){
            session()->set('message','No tiene permisos para acceder a la opción de '.$ruta);
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

El middleware de las funciones:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use Debugbar;

class Funciones{

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth){
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ruta, $func){
        if($func=='crear'){
            $results = DB::select("select exists(select * FROM perfiles_funciones AS pf INNER JOIN funciones AS f ON f.id = pf.id_funciones INNER JOIN perfiles AS p ON p.id = pf.id_perfiles WHERE pf.id_perfiles = :id AND f.titulo = :ruta AND pf.crear = 't')",
                [
                'id' => ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles),
                'ruta'=>($ruta)
                ]);
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        if($func=='editar'){
            $results = DB::select("select exists(select * FROM perfiles_funciones AS pf INNER JOIN funciones AS f ON f.id = pf.id_funciones INNER JOIN perfiles AS p ON p.id = pf.id_perfiles WHERE pf.id_perfiles = :id AND f.titulo = :ruta AND pf.editar = 't')",
                [
                'id' => ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles),
                'ruta'=>($ruta)
                ]);
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        if($func=='eliminar'){
            $results = DB::select("select exists(select * FROM perfiles_funciones AS pf INNER JOIN funciones AS f ON f.id = pf.id_funciones INNER JOIN perfiles AS p ON p.id = pf.id_perfiles WHERE pf.id_perfiles = :id AND f.titulo = :ruta AND pf.eliminar = 't')",
                [
                'id' => ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles),
                'ruta'=>($ruta)
                ]);
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        if($func=='estado'){
            $results = DB::select("select exists(select * FROM perfiles_funciones AS pf INNER JOIN funciones AS f ON f.id = pf.id_funciones INNER JOIN perfiles AS p ON p.id = pf.id_perfiles WHERE pf.id_perfiles = :id AND f.titulo = :ruta AND pf.estado = 't')",
                [
                'id' => ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles),
                'ruta'=>($ruta)
                ]);
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Archivo kernel donde defino los middleware:

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'ruta' => \App\Http\Middleware\Ruta::class,
        'funciones' => \App\Http\Middleware\Funciones::class,
    ];
```

Compruebo con `debugbar` el resultado del `sql` y es el resultado esperado pero no bloquea la acción a la `url` como entrara a la condición.

**Actualización 1**
modifique la consulta que realizo en el middleware de la siguiente manera:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use Debugbar;

class Funciones{

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth){
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ruta, $func){
        if($func=='crear'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.crear', 't')
                        ->exists();
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        if($func=='editar'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.editar', 't')
                        ->exists();
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        if($func=='eliminar'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.eliminar', 't')
                        ->exists();
            Debugbar::error($results);
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        if($func=='estado'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.estado', 't')
                        ->exists();
            if($results){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pero ahora me lanza el siguiente error:

> ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 136: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Cual es el midleware que te deja pasar, aún cuando el resultado de la consulta es correcta?

Comment: el de las funciones

Comment: @HammerffallBK acomo de la pregunta, anoche estuve revisando y revisando hasta q ahora no ignora la condicion sino que ahora me lanza un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma que lo hace laravel es lanzar una axcepcion al final, en caso de no llamar a `return $next($request);`
En el fichero `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` colocas el error en el arreglo

```
protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
    \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
    \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
    \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    \App\Exceptions\FunctionException::class // error sobre tu midleware
];
```

En render debes colocar

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($e instanceof FunctionException) {
        return $e->errorEnFunciones();
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

colocas una función `errorEnFunciones`

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, FunctionException $exception){......}
```

dentro del cual pudes hacer una redirección, como esta en la función `unauthenticated`

Claro importas

```
use App\Exceptions\FunctionException;
```

Que debe quedar algo asi

**app/Exceptions/FunctionException.php**

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class FunctionException extends Exception
{

    protected $guards;


    public function __construct($message = 'Error en funciones.', array $guards = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($message);

        $this->guards = $guards;
    }


    public function guards()
    {
        return $this->guards;
    }
}
```

y sobre tu midleware al final llamas

```
throw new FunctionException('Error en funciones.', $guards);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo es una alternativa al error que arrojaba.

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado:** 
en la primera acualizacion muestro un error que me daba el middleware, simplemente saque el `return $next($request);` de la condición y la condicion la invertí.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use Debugbar;

class Funciones{

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth){
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ruta, $func){
        if($func=='crear'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.crear', 't')
                        ->exists();
            if(!$results){
                $ruta = strtolower($ruta);
                return redirect('/'.$ruta);
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        if($func=='editar'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.editar', 't')
                        ->exists();
            if(!$results){
                $ruta = strtolower($ruta);
                return redirect('/'.$ruta);
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        if($func=='eliminar'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.eliminar', 't')
                        ->exists();
            Debugbar::error($results);
            if(!$results){
                $ruta = strtolower($ruta);
                return redirect('/'.$ruta);
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        if($func=='estado'){
            $results = DB::table('perfiles_funciones AS pf')
                        ->join('funciones AS f','pf.id_funciones','=','f.id')
                        ->join('perfiles AS p','pf.id_perfiles','=','p.id')
                        ->where('pf.id_perfiles', ($this->auth->user()->id_perfiles))
                        ->where('f.titulo', ($ruta))
                        ->where('pf.estado', 't')
                        ->exists();
            if(!$results){
                $ruta = strtolower($ruta);
                return redirect('/'.$ruta);
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O podias hacer eso, a la solución que propone laravel